# SQLiteConnection databases leak when running emulator

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-database

I was running the emulator and received the following errors about memory leak. It was interesting that the leaking database seems to be of the Google gms instead of a user database. Does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks!

```
09-27 15:55:07.252 2058-2068/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/metrics.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

09-27 15:55:07.255 2058-2068/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/help_responses.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.

09-27 15:55:07.259 2058-2068/com.google.android.gms W/SQLiteConnectionPool: A SQLiteConnection object for database '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/auto_complete_suggestions.db' was leaked!  Please fix your application to end transactions in progress properly and to close the database when it is no longer needed.
```

Comment: Looks like an error in `com.google.android.gms` code...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Open Settings - Apps - Google Play Services - MANAGE SPACE - CLEAR ALL DATA

Comment: Just a note, you might have to look around a bit on different emulators. I found this under ...Google Play Services > Settings > MANAGE SPACE... on a Nexus 5X emulator.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you aren't using the `disconnect()` method of your `GoogleApiClient`

See [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.html#disconnect()) for more.